# Transposing columnar record data to rows in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOB2t.gif]

Can I reference a cell in another worksheet like this?

Example:

```
Worksheet A
A1 Data1
A2 
A3 Data2
A4 
A5 Data3
```

Worksheet B (I want to copy by referencing the cells in Worksheet A)

> `B1 'Worksheet A'!A1`
>    `B2 'Worksheet A'!(A1+2)` ~ meaning I want to copy cell `'Worksheet A'!A3`
>    `B3 'Worksheet A'!(A3+2)` ~ meaning I want to copy cell `'Worksheet A'!A5` ... Note that `A3` in this formula comes from the formula in `B2` by skipping one row in `Worksheet A`.
>    `B4 'Worksheet A'!(A5+2)`

The reason for this is so that I can skip the A2 and A4 cells and be able to drag the formula in Worksheet B to extend it without the need to point manually each cell that I want to copy from Worksheet A.

Comment: Whoa... Detailing your explanation would be good. All I can say, quickly like that, is that you can very well, when you're allowed to select your data with your mouse, click another worksheet and select data from there. The code generated should guide you.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably put the headers easily, but the data, you can use this for the first column:

```
=INDEX(Sheet5!$A:$A,(ROW()-1)*4-1)
```

This one for the second:

```
=INDEX(Sheet5!$A:$A,(ROW()-1)*4)
```

This one for the third:

```
=INDEX(Sheet5!$A:$A,(ROW()-1)*4+1)
```

If it weren't for the picture, I would have given up trying to understand you! xD

+1 for this :)

Answer (score 0):

Layman method without using a formula:

1) insert an extra column on left. Lets call this 'column label'

2) label each of the cells in the data column until you've got repeated pattern (given the data is in a repeated order)

3) fill in the rest of the cells using the completed 'column label' pattern

4) use the filter to sort/filter by the column label

5) copy and paste sorted data into relevant columns

The order should remain the same

[Before sorting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqERD.png)

[Sorted and can just be copy/pasted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZhfg.png)